# How can I shorten this substitution cipher code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

> The input string will consist of only alphabetic characters. The function should return a string where all characters have been moved "up" two spots in the alphabet.
>
> For example:
>
> - "a" will become "c"
> - "z" will become "b"

I wrote this code, but I think it's too long. How can I make it shorter and better?

```
def encrypt_message(strings: str) -> str:
    our_al = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i", 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u',
              'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    new_s = ""
    for character in strings:
        index = our_al.index(character)
        if index <= 23:
            index += 2
            new_s += our_al[index]
        elif index == 24:
            new_s += our_al[0]
        elif index == 25:
            new_s += our_al[1]

    return new_s


print(encrypt_message("abc"))
print(encrypt_message("xyz"))
print(encrypt_message(""))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some utils will be beneficial. If you use this function repeatedly you don't always want to iterate the chars to find the index, hence the lookup `dict`.

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as al

index = {c: i for i, c in enumerate(al)}

def encrypt_message(s: str) -> str:
    return ''.join(al[(index[c] + 2) % 26] for c in s)

>>> encrypt_message('xyz')
'zab'
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `itertools.islice` and `itertools.cycle` to get the next character (that is located 2 positions forward):

```
from itertools import islice, cycle
from string import ascii_lowercase

def get_next_2(c):
    index = ascii_lowercase.index(c)
    return next(islice(cycle(ascii_lowercase), index + 2, None))

def encrypt_message(strings):
    return ''.join(map(get_next_2, strings))
```

if you like one line solution you can use:

```
from string import ascii_lowercase as al

def encrypt_message(strings):
    return ''.join([al[(al.index(c) + 2) % 26] for c in strings])
```

Comment: i should try all 3 solutions to get familiar with them. thank you for your one line code ..

Comment: Don't know if you knew and did this on purpose, but `str.join` is one of the functions that performs better with a list comprehension than a generator expression, so +1. 
I still tend to use the latter for aesthetic reasons :D

Answer (score 0):

You can make two improvements:

- use the string module to get the letters of the alphabet

  - string.ascii_lowercase is a string of all the lowercase ASCII letters (you just need an iterable here, not necessarily a list, so a string is fine)
- use the modulus operator (`%`) to simplify the calculations

  - the modulus operator "wraps around" the calculations, so `(25 + 2) % 26` evaluates to `1`

```
def encrypt_message(strings: str) -> str:
    new_s = ""
    for character in strings:
        if character not in string.ascii_lowercase:
            continue
        index = string.ascii_lowercase.index(character)
        new_index = (index + 2) % len(string.ascii_lowercase)
        new_s += string.ascii_lowercase[new_index]
    return new_s
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also convert the character to their ASCII value, add two and convert them back.

```
for character in strings:
    if character not in string.ascii_lowercase:
        continue
    index = ord(character) - 96
    new_index = (index + 2) % 26 + 96 # a is 97
return chr(new_index)
```